# How can we implement +/- 10% for value logic in java

Tags: java

I have a requirement where i have to check file size, we are given a file sizes document where the corresponding file can be of +/- 10% of size mentioned in the document, is there any way in java which can do this job easily other than calculating the 10% of the size value and comparing the original value with + 10% & -10% ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `if (fileSize >= expectedSize * 0.9 && fileSize <= expectedSize * 1.1)`

Answer (score 2):

This post is pretty vague, so this answer is also going to be pretty vague. Let's say documentSize is the actual size of the document and mentionedSize is the size mentioned in the document. The following code probably does what you want.

```
if ( (0.9 * mentionedSize) <= documentSize && documentSize <= (1.1 * documentSize) ) {
    //do stuff
}
else {
    //do other stuff
}
```